# How to mock an interface?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

Here is a question about Mockito. For the following code,

```
public class ABC implements someInterface() {
    public void test() {
        someFunction(new A(), this);
    }
}
```

`someFunction` accepts an instance of class A and a callback that implements `someInterface` as parameter. When using `powermock` to mock new instance creation, we can use

```
whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mMockClass);
```

then we can get the mock A class.

The question is how do I mock the second parameter?

Comment: is your codesample the test code? or the code under test? The mock depends on what are you trying to test.

Comment: The code sample is the code that I am going to test.

Comment: If you want to test the Class `ABC` and function `test()`, then you have to create a "normal" instance of it `abc = new ABC();abc.test();` and than there is no need to mock itself.
May be you want to wrap it in a Spy and verify for call of `someFunction`
If you want to test the `someFunction`, you should call it directly with known mocks.
something like `someFunction(Mockito.mock(A.class),Mockito.mock(someInterface.class));`

Answer (score 1):

For handling the first parameter, you can use https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation or you can use the `any()` matcher.

For the second parameter, just pass the reference of the class you're testing in your test method to the class.  For example,

```
...
ABC abc = new ABC();
Foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
Foo.someFunction(Mockito.any(), abc);

abc.test();
...
```